# Stop TCustomHint from centering itself around my point

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I'm trying to use `TCustomHint` to show a message to my user that fades in and out nicely, to not be too distracting. However when I call `ShowHint` on my object with a point, the hint box appears to center itself around the point I give. What I would like is to have my box appear such that its top-left coordinate is the point given.

Here's the code I'm using so show the hint:

```
procedure ShowNotification(ATitle: UnicodeString; AMsg: UnicodeString);
var
  Box: TCustomHint;
  P: TPoint;
begin
    Box := TCustomHint.Create(MyForm);
    Box.Title := ATitle;
    Box.Description := AMsg;
    Box.Delay := 0;
    Box.HideAfter := 5000;
    Box.Style := bhsStandard;

    P.X := 0;
    P.Y := 0;

    Box.ShowHint(P);
end;
```

I know that my point's X/Y coordinates are not relative to the form, and that's not the issue.

I've traced through what happens when I call `ShowHint` and it appears that if I can somehow control the final width of the underlying `TCustomHintWindow` inside of `TCustomHint.ShowHint(Rect: TRect)` then I may be in business.

So my question is: is there an obvious way to stop a `TCustomHint` from centering itself at my point? Or will I have to go through the process of inheriting, overriding the draw method, etc etc? I hope I'm just missing something simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no particularly easy way to do what you want. The `TCustomHint` class is designed to serve a very specific purpose. It was designed to be used by the `TControl.CustomHint` property. You can see how it is called by looking at the code for `TCustomHint.ShowHint`. The pertinent excerpts are:

```
if Control.CustomHint = Self then
begin
  ....
  GetCursorPos(Pos);
end
else
  Pos := Control.ClientToScreen(Point(Control.Width div 2, Control.Height));
ShowHint(Pos);
```

So, either the control is shown centred horizontally around the current cursor position, or centred horizontally around the middle of the associated control.

I think the bottom line here is that `TCustomHint` is not designed to be used the way you are using it.

Anyway, there is a rather gruesome way to make your code do what you want. You can create a temporary `TCustomHintWindow` that you never show and use it to work out the width of the hint window that you want to show. And then use that to shift the point that you pass to the real hint window. In order to make it fly you need to crack the private members of `TCustomHintWindow`.

```
type
  TCustomHintWindowCracker = class helper for TCustomHintWindow
  private
    procedure SetTitleDescription(const Title, Description: string);
  end;

procedure TCustomHintWindowCracker.SetTitleDescription(const Title, Description: string);
begin
  Self.FTitle := Title;
  Self.FDescription := Description;
end;

procedure ShowNotification(ATitle: UnicodeString; AMsg: UnicodeString);
var
  Box: TCustomHint;
  SizingWindow: TCustomHintWindow;
  P: TPoint;
begin
  Box := TCustomHint.Create(Form5);
  Box.Title := ATitle;
  Box.Description := AMsg;
  Box.Delay := 0;
  Box.HideAfter := 5000;
  Box.Style := bhsStandard;

  P := Point(0, 0);
  SizingWindow := TCustomHintWindow.Create(nil);
  try
    SizingWindow.HintParent := Box;
    SizingWindow.HandleNeeded;
    SizingWindow.SetTitleDescription(ATitle, AMsg);
    SizingWindow.AutoSize;
    inc(P.X, SizingWindow.Width div 2);
  finally
    SizingWindow.Free;
  end;
  Box.ShowHint(P);
end;
```

This does what you asked, but honestly, it makes me feel rather queasy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm going to have to stew over whether it's better to do it this way, or if I should just use TCustomHint as "inspiration" and just build my own class from the ground up. Leaning more toward the latter.